# Was Baze Malbus previously a Guardian of the Whills?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, chirrut-imwe

In the Rogue One scene in the prison cell on Jedah, Baze Malbus makes fun of Chirrut Îmwe "praying" for the cell door to open. Chirrut responds with:

> Baze Malbus was once the most devoted guardian of us all.

Other than this line, do we have any evidence Baze used to be a Guardian of the Whills? It would tie in nicely with a later scene where

> after Chirrut's death, he appears to regain his "faith" in the Force as he repeats his fallen friend's mantra.

Comment: He actually says a reply to his fallen friends mantra

Comment: What an odd question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Yes, he absolutely was

In the novelization, Baze is identified as a Guardian on several occasions:

- By Cassian, after Chirrut accosts Jyn about her necklace:

  > "We're not here to make friends," [Cassian] muttered. "Not with those guys."
  >
  > "Who are they?"
  >
  > "The Guardians of the Whills. Protectors of the Temple of the Kyber. But there's nothing left to protect, so now they're just causing trouble for everybody."
  >
  > <sup>Chapter 4</sup>
- By Chirrut himself, in the quote you remember:

  > Chirrut's partner laughed again. The sound was brief and ugly, but Chirrut only shrugged and told Cassian, "Baze Malbus was once the most devoted Guardian of us all."
  >
  > *Baze Malbus*. Cassian ran the name through his mental database and came up empty. "Now he's just *your* guardian?” he asked.
  >
  > Neither man took the bait. Cassian ran his hands over his face, scratched at his beard. Both of the Guardians were formidable fighters, to be sure
  >
  > <sup>Chapter 5</sup>

  There are also a large number of occasions where Baze and Chirrut are described as "the Guardians", in the plural; but I'm not going to quote every one of them.
- In the narration (emphasis mine):

  > Cassian tried to interpose his body between Baze and the cell door as the Guardian straightened with purpose.
  >
  > <sup>Chapter 6</sup>

  > He was certain Chirrut understood his warning. But the blind man, **once brother to Baze among the Guardians of the Whills** and now the fool Baze was cursed to entertain, started forward again.
  >
  > <sup>Chapter 10</sup>
- And, most importantly, in Baze's own internal narration:

  > "The Force is with me," he repeated. "And I am with the Force."
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > He spoke the words, and in them he found not comfort but conviction — or the memory of conviction, as if the words were a key to the forgotten faith of his youth. The unlocked memory strangled him, wracking and intense. He knew again the significance of the Force in every breath and action, knew all he had forsaken in years past; saw the vast gulf between the Guardian he had been
  >   and the man he was now, and wept in his heart for both.
  >
  > <sup>Chapter 20</sup>

And in the Visual Guide:

- [image]

  > Former Guardian of the Whills Baze Malbus has found a more concrete cause in fighting the Empire. A combat-hardened veteran of countless skirmishes on embattled Jedha and elsewhere, Baze has a bravado that provides a marked contrast to the spiritual centeredness of his best friend and moral compass, Chirrut  Îmwe. Baze's faith has seemingly evaporated in the fires of Jedha
- [image]

  > Though both are Guardians of the Whills, Baze and Chirrut could not be more different in their approach to combat.

And on the official [Star Wars Twitter](https://twitter.com/starwars/status/816743375105708032) feed:

[image]

> **@StarWars** Baze Malbus. A former Guardian of the Whills dedicated to the fight against the Empire. #RogueOne

Comment: That's a mighty fuzzy picture. Did you take it with your fridge?

Comment: @Valorum Nah, I nicked it. I'd be delighted if you (or anyone else, for that matter) were to replace it with a clearer one

Comment: I'm mobile at present. I'll sort it when I get back home unless it's been resolved before then.